# Multiple search options, single field, selected via drop down - js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I'm trying to essentially create a drop down menu tied to a field that allows me to search multiple sections of the back end of a site by choosing which section to search using the drop down.

What this will entail is assigning a variable to represent the input from the form and scripting to toggle between the different query strings that that variable will be used to complete.

At this point I'm basically just lost as to how to structure the javascript required to accomplish this.

Can I tie each query string to each option using an id and then create a function that runs when the form itself is submitted, constructing the needed query URL by combining the variable with the base URL included in the javascript?

Basically I need, say, the text dropdown selection to tell the page that it will be appending %query% to http://example.com/content/text/?q= when the form is submitted and letting the system handle the rest.

I would sincerely appreciate some input on how to structure the js/jquery to accomplish that. I know I need to tie the variable to the field and the URLs to be completed to the drop down based on ID but I'm not totally sure how.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do: You are trying to redirect to a different  url based on the drop down selection on form submit? Some input from the form has to be included as a query string for the new URL.

Comment: That's it exactly. I just need the drop down to dictate which URL is being completed with what is entered in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some jsFiddle examples of what you might want to do:

1. Pass the search term and dropdown select field in the query string to one page and have the page do something based on the choices. **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pay84/1/)**
2. Pass the search term to a page specified by the dropdown select field. **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pay84/2/)**
3. Pass the search term to a URL specified by the dropdown select field. **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pay84/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do.

Have a eventhandler for onsubmit

In YourMehtod(){
1. get dropdown selection
2. get the URL and append query string
3.window.open(url,"_self")
}